# How to show cell values of raster in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, saga

I would like to know if it is possible to display a raster cell value in the center of a cell with ArcGIS in the same way that SAGA-GIS does when you zoom in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Pixel Inspector tool for dynamic viewing

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t00000097000000

Or, could convert the raster to points and label by the values

Answer (score 1):

Here is a work around that accomplishes what you want by creating a shapefile of points in the center of each cell:

```
RasterToPoint_conversion (in_raster, out_point_features, raster_field)
```

Set display fill to "None"

Label points as values, no offset.